# Remove demo store notice from admin side in magento 2.2.5?

Tags: admin-panel, magento-2.2.5

How to remove/disable demo store notice from admin side.
We want to remove from only admin side but we want that show in front.
Our site is in magento 2.2.5
Any one help me for solve this issue.

Comment: @Nikul can you paste your solution if you have done ?

Answer (score 0):

Just override block Magento\Backend\Block\Page\Notices for disable demo store notification only for admin section.

Create **Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Backend\Block\Page\Notices" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Notices"/>
</config>
```

Create **Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Notices.php** file

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Page;

class Notices extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Page\Notices
{
     /**
     * Check if demo store notice should be displayed
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function displayDemoNotice()
    {

        /*return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'design/head/demonotice',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );*/

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: please clarify I do not understand..

Comment: This is called Preference right? @Ansar Husain

Comment: Yes @Gem right.